# Import third party JS library in react with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new user to react using redux. I want to include some third party reporting tool library(reporting tool name --> logi) into my existing react with redux application. I tried to include that library in index.html file but I am not able to use functions from that library to individual component.

I am not getting the way to import that library in react component. Here I am trying application with react-create-app.

Please help me with the same.

Thanks

Comment: Library name...

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "rdEmbed.js" its a logi reporting tool provided library to generate widgets and reports.